# Cannot 'merge' 'DataFrameGroupBy'

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, one the columns is categorical data and the rest is float. I separate these two based on the type of the data. both dataframe have timestamps and time stamps is their index.

I am trying to aggregate the stats of the numeric data and also most frequent label for categorical data for 5min. I deal with the each type separately but I cant assemble the two group back together.

```
Telemetry=All[FLOATTYPE]
grouped = Telemetry.groupby(Telemetry.index.floor('5T'))
# computing various stats
grouped1 = grouped.agg([ 'mean','std'])
Category=All[CATEGORICALTYPE]
grouped2 = Category.groupby(Category.index.floor('5T'))
grouped2=grouped2.agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0] if len(x.dropna())!=0 else np.nan)

grouped = grouped.merge( grouped2, axis=1)

AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'merge' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Is there any way to avoid this issue by doing it with one line like:

```
grouped1 = grouped.agg(lambda x: [ 'mean','std'] if x.astype(float) else  (x.value_counts().index[0] if len(x.dropna())!=0 else np.nan) )
```

or merge both group together based on their Index and avoid the error.

Comment: I think you want `grouped = grouped1.merge( grouped2, axis=1)`

Comment: @PaulH Thank you for answering, I change it to `grouped = grouped1.merge( grouped2, axis=1)`  and I am getting `TypeError: merge() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'!
`

Comment: @PaulH  I changed it to `grouped3 = grouped.join(grouped2,how='left')`  and seems that it is working.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `join` in place of `merge` which by default aligns indexes between both dataframes.

```
final = grouped1.join(grouped2)
```

However, you want to flatten the hierarchical columns resulting from the multiple aggregate `groupby` of *Telemetry* to avoid different level unintended result (where warning will be raised):

```
grouped1 = Telemetry.groupby(Telemetry.index.floor('5T')).agg([ 'mean','std'])

from itertools import product

newcols = [str(i[0])+'_'+i[1]
           for i in list(product(grouped1.columns.levels[0], grouped1.columns.levels[1]))]
grouped1.columns = newcols
```

---

Below demonstrates with reproducible example

Data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import time

LETTERS = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')    
epoch_time = int(time.time())

np.random.seed(1001)
ALL = pd.DataFrame({'NUM1': np.random.randn(50)*100,
                    'NUM2': np.random.uniform(0,1,50),                   
                    'NUM3': np.random.randint(100, size=50),                                             
                    'CAT1': ["".join(np.random.choice(LETTERS,1)) for _ in range(50)],
                    'CAT2': ["".join(np.random.choice(['pandas', 'r', 'julia', 'sas', 'stata', 'spss'],1)) for _ in range(50)],              
                    'CAT3': ["".join(np.random.choice(['postgres', 'mysql', 'sqlite', 'oracle', 'sql server', 'db2'],1)) for _ in range(50)]}, 
                   index=[dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(np.random.randint(epoch_time - 5000, epoch_time)) for _ in range(50)])
```

Aggregation

```
from itertools import product

# NUMERIC COLS --------------------------------------------------
Telemetry = ALL.filter(regex='NUM', axis=1)

grouped1 = Telemetry.groupby(Telemetry.index.floor('5T')).agg([ 'mean','std'])

newcols = [str(i[0])+'_'+i[1]
           for i in list(product(grouped1.columns.levels[0], grouped1.columns.levels[1]))]
grouped1.columns = newcols

# CATEGORY COLS -------------------------------------------------
Category = ALL.filter(regex='CAT', axis=1)

grouped2 = Category.groupby(Category.index.floor('5T'))\
                   .agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0] if len(x.dropna())!=0 else np.nan)

final = grouped1.join(grouped2)
```

Output

```
print(final)

#                       NUM1_mean    NUM1_std  NUM2_mean  NUM2_std  NUM3_mean   NUM3_std CAT1    CAT2     CATR3
# 2018-03-13 13:55:00  -17.516103   59.562954   0.530788  0.217159  67.000000  17.568912    I   julia    sqlite
# 2018-03-13 14:00:00   85.189272         NaN   0.842956       NaN  43.000000        NaN    Y     sas    oracle
# 2018-03-13 14:05:00  -16.833329  201.004717   0.737183  0.332332  55.500000  38.890873    M    spss  postgres
# 2018-03-13 14:10:00   84.936984   80.634218   0.754657  0.110415  80.600000  17.213367    V   stata    oracle
# 2018-03-13 14:15:00   99.512503   11.492072   0.521307  0.250584  23.500000  30.405592    E  pandas    sqlite
# 2018-03-13 14:20:00  -90.749756   65.721659   0.459464  0.377603  35.250000  30.192438    G     sas       db2
# 2018-03-13 14:25:00  -56.271685  104.440802   0.496268  0.348611  56.500000  28.310775    K    spss  postgres
# 2018-03-13 14:30:00   55.369341   50.215679   0.600296  0.399855  65.000000  41.004065    P       r       db2
# 2018-03-13 14:40:00  184.546043         NaN   0.892016       NaN  84.000000        NaN    W   julia       db2
# 2018-03-13 14:45:00  -93.886027   61.489475   0.498042  0.286001  48.000000  25.429641    W   stata  postgres
# 2018-03-13 14:50:00  122.819400         NaN   0.168059       NaN  41.000000        NaN    S   stata    sqlite
# 2018-03-13 14:55:00  -34.318532   40.225336   0.756454  0.335583  26.666667  21.385353    F   stata    sqlite
# 2018-03-13 15:00:00   -2.329881         NaN   0.894770       NaN  73.000000        NaN    Y     sas  postgres
# 2018-03-13 15:05:00  -86.408659   31.446422   0.618246  0.158136  52.000000  59.396970    G   julia  postgres
# 2018-03-13 15:10:00  -20.309460  121.773576   0.479996  0.394707  52.000000  42.585209    U     sas    oracle
# 2018-03-13 15:15:00   -5.493293  217.143835   0.478187  0.530773  59.500000  55.861436    E   stata  postgres
```